# About spinner Item Selection in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've problem with my spinner in fragment.I select spinner item and in that fragment on button click call another **fragment-2** after return to fragment spinner select next item position. How it happen I couldn't understand. How will be stay on selected position before I call to **fragment-2**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: fragment class with xml

Comment: ya nobody's god around here!

Comment: Post your code dear with out code how can we solve your problem

Comment: thank you sir i get the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a static variable in the Activity which holds your fragments, and that variable will hold the position of the selected item. Initialize it with -1, so when it's not -1 just select the spinner position with this variable. sounds good?